# Can I add columns to the Assembly Bill of Materials print in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am working with Assembly/Bill of Material records in netsuite. When you print the Bill of Materials it displays a table with the members Name, Assembly Quantity, and the Total Quantity. Am I able to add a column for the members description into this table?

I have found some support articles, but none of which show how to add columns to this table print.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a saved search and then Advanced PDF templates.

Create a Saved Item Search: `Type=Assembly/Bill of Materials`

Create/Enable Advanced PDF/HTML templates. 
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48703/kw/advanced%20pdf%20html

`Customization-->Forms-->Advanced Templates`, create a new form using the saved search you've created.

You can now customize this form to add whatever information you need. You can modify the saved search to include the column that you'd like, and modify the template to make it look however you want.

You can use the template editor within Netsuite, or you can customize it yourself using CSS and HTML. Netsuite also uses BFO and Freemarker to render/design templates. (You'll need to know the ID's of each field you add in the template I believe)

Hope this helps. (And I'm not just wildly wrong)

Comment: I will try this out this afternoon and report back. Thank you!

Comment: if I am on my Serialized/Assembly Bill of Materials record in netsuite, and use the little printer icon to print. I dont think this is a html or pdf template that displays. Its just a table with the members Name, Assembly Quantity, and the Total Quantity as columns. Is there a way to edit this table report that displays to add a column?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can always use a saved search to show what columns you need.